# feh: maintain zoom setting

Tags: images, feh

When browsing through the images in a directory with `feh`, the magnification can be changed by use of the up/down arrow keys, but the setting is lost as soon as the next image in the series is loaded. Is there a way to apply the magnification setting selected for image i to image i+1? If not, is this possible in another lightweight image viewer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the context menu for the right mouse button in the image, there is: **Options** -> **Keep viewport zoom & pos**.

That should do just what you need.

To start `feh` with that option set:

```
$ feh --keep-zoom-vp ...
```

To set the option by default:

```
alias feh="feh --keep-zoom-vp"
```

Comment: Thank you. I notice that this works well for certain image formats (e.g., png, jpeg) but not for tif files. In this case, the image displays, but the viewport settings change each time a new image is loaded (along with printing to standard error of the message: "TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 37553 (0x92b1) encountered.").

Comment: The command-line flag for this option is `--keep-zoom-vp`

Comment: You can create an alias to make it default `alias feh="feh --keep-zoom-vp"`